# crontab does not work combined with ruby/middleman CENTOS

Tags: ruby, cron, centos, middleman

I am trying to run a cronjob which triggers a middleman server to build my project every minute. I ran into various problems with the crontab environment not being the same as my shell environment and tried pretty much EVERY combination out there which supposedly helps, including specifying the full path to everything, setting the variables inside the cronjob and many other things. The issue still remains: For some reason, when executing from the shell, `middleman build` does exactly what it should.

When I put the exact same line into a script called launcher.sh:

```
source $HOME/.bash_profile
cd /home/ec2-user/git_directory/ && git pull
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.5/bin/middleman build
```

and I run the script from the command line, it works perfectly (i.e. gets the current repo and then builds it).

When I run it from within a cronjob, I am getting all kinds of weird errors. My crontab looks as follows:

```
SHELL=/bin/bash
* * * * * sh $HOME/launcher.sh
```

and the error I am getting is

```
/usr/bin/env: ruby_executable_hooks: No such file or directory
```

I don't understand why, given the same environments, running the very same command from the command line vs. from crontab makes a difference. Can anyone point me into the right direction here?

Thanks!

Comment: Is this a root crontab or your own user crontab? I'm guessing RVM is not loaded properly.

Comment: @nonick : How did you ensure that the envrionment when run from crontab is the same as from the command line? In this case, I would first of all check that the PATH is identical.

Comment: @user1934428 : I am setting the PATH in crontab to be the same as the output from "echo $PATH"

Comment: @Casper : i am calling "crontab -e" as user (not root). I tried it as root as well, but same problem :(

Comment: This should help. How to run RVM scripts from crontab: https://rvm.io/deployment/cron

Comment: @nonick : In the snippet you posted, I see only the `SHELL` variable being defined in the crontab, which I find odd, because you set it to be `bash`, but you run your script bei `sh`. Wouldn't it make sense then to run your script under bash? And, I don't see that you would define PATH in your crontab. Maybe it would be helpful if we can see all relevant crontab lines.

Comment: @user1934428 : sorry, the snippet was not complete, however switching to sh in combination with what Casper suggested actually worked!! So thank you very much!

Comment: @Casper : The link you posted about rvm + cron led me to the solution, explicitly specifying that path helped. Thanks a lot!